# Cant get helloWorld Loaded on AVD

Tags: android

My Helloworld tutorial sample builds and runs just fine, except it doesn't show the text (i.e. loads apps). The only thing I see is that Emulator (Target 2.2 API level 8) comes up with just the "Android" in it. and then the emulator shows up a locked up screen in a while. Here is output from the console

```
[2010-09-20 10:36:55 - HelloAndroid] Android Launch!
[2010-09-20 10:36:55 - HelloAndroid] adb is running normally.
[2010-09-20 10:36:55 - HelloAndroid] Performing com.example.HelloAndroid.HelloAndroid activity launch
[2010-09-20 10:36:55 - HelloAndroid] Automatic Target Mode: Preferred AVD 'my_avd' is not available. Launching new emulator.
[2010-09-20 10:37:56 - HelloAndroid] WARNING: Application does not specify an API level requirement!
[2010-09-20 10:37:56 - HelloAndroid] Device API version is 8 (Android 2.2)
[2010-09-20 10:37:56 - HelloAndroid] HOME is up on device 'emulator-5554'
[2010-09-20 10:38:23 - HelloAndroid] Uploading HelloAndroid.apk onto device 'emulator-5554'
[2010-09-20 10:38:27 - HelloAndroid] Installing HelloAndroid.apk...
```

After I exit the emulator, I get the following errors.

```
[2010-09-20 09:02:24 - DeviceMonitor]Sending jdwp tracking request failed!
[2010-09-20 09:38:46 - ddms]null
java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.android.ddmlib.JdwpPacket.writeAndConsume(Jdwp Packet.java:213)
at com.android.ddmlib.Client.sendAndConsume(Client.ja va:573)
at com.android.ddmlib.HandleHello.sendHELO(HandleHell o.java:142)
at com.android.ddmlib.HandleHello.sendHelloCommands(H andleHello.java:65)
at com.android.ddmlib.Client.getJdwpPacket(Client.jav a:670)
at com.android.ddmlib.MonitorThread.processClientActi vity(MonitorThread.java:317)
at com.android.ddmlib.MonitorThread.run(MonitorThread .java:263)

[2010-09-20 09:38:47 - ddms]null
java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.android.ddmlib.JdwpPacket.writeAndConsume(Jdwp Packet.java:213)
at com.android.ddmlib.Client.sendAndConsume(Client.ja va:573)
at com.android.ddmlib.HandleHello.sendHELO(HandleHell o.java:142)
at com.android.ddmlib.HandleHello.sendHelloCommands(H andleHello.java:65)
at com.android.ddmlib.Client.getJdwpPacket(Client.jav a:670)
at com.android.ddmlib.MonitorThread.processClientActi vity(MonitorThread.java:317)
at com.android.ddmlib.MonitorThread.run(MonitorThread .java:263)

[2010-09-20 09:50:11 - DeviceMonitor]Sending jdwp tracking request failed!
[2010-09-20 09:59:29 - DeviceMonitor]Sending jdwp tracking request failed!
[2010-09-20 09:59:31 - Logcat]device not found
com.android.ddmlib.AdbCommandRejectedException: device not found
at com.android.ddmlib.AdbHelper.setDevice(AdbHelper.j ava:736)
at com.android.ddmlib.AdbHelper.executeRemoteCommand( AdbHelper.java:373)
at com.android.ddmlib.Device.executeShellCommand(Devi ce.java:285)
at com.android.ddmuilib.logcat.LogPanel$3.run(LogPane l.java:516)

[2010-09-20 10:40:46 - DeviceMonitor]Sending jdwp tracking request failed!
```

Also, is there a way to capture the TEXT from CMD window that runs while the Emulator is coming up?

Comment: provide some code please! have you set up the emulator correctly? What do you mean with capture? I assume you use eclipse. In Eclipse the log is saved as long as you do not delete it. But there is a button to export the log too. Is Installing HelloAndroid.apk... successful?

Answer (score 0):

Simply press on the Menu button in the emulator.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what your console has to say,by any means your eclipse is unable to add the minimum sdkversion to your manifest

```
WARNING: Application does not specify an API level requirement!
```

just add the following code to your manifest file and check whether it works or not,also close any open xml file prior to running your application

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" />
```

give it a try and say what happens